# java Optional: a good way to not having to do nested ifPresent()

Tags: java, java-8

I frequently have to do something as below

```
// some method
public T blah() {
    Optional<T> oneOp = getFromSomething();
    if (oneOp.isPresent()) {
        Optional<T> secondOp = getFromSomethingElse(oneOp.get())
        if (secondOp.isPresent()) {
            return secondOp.get()
        }
    }
    return DEFAULT_VALUE;
}
```

it's pretty cumbersome to keep checking for ifPresent() as if i am back to doing the null check

Comment: Try ‘flatMap’ & ‘orElse’.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [the `flatMap` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) which will, if present, replace the `Optional` with another `Optional`, using the supplied `Function`.

> If a value is present, returns the result of applying the given `Optional`-bearing mapping function to the value, otherwise returns an empty `Optional`.

Then, you can use [`orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse(T)) that will, if present, return the value or else the default value you supply.

> If a value is present, returns the value, otherwise returns `other`.

Here, I also turned the call to `getFromSomethingElse` into a method reference that will match the `Function` required by `flatMap`.

```
public T blah() {
    return getFromSomething().flatMap(this::getFromSomethingElse).orElse(DEFAULT_VALUE);
}
```